Suggestions for Replacing our LOUD Kitchen Ceiling Exhaust Vent
We just bought a house with a range in the middle of the small kitchen. There's no hood and no built-in exhaust on the GE range itself. A large exhaust vent is on the ceiling directly above. It's around 20" x 40" -- https://imgur.com/a/af1JN9A

It's controlled by a wall knob with I think five variable settings, but with a 9' ceiling, it has to be on one of the highest settings to be effective. The highest settings are super loud, and I'd like to replace it with something powerful but quiet. We cook a ton and the exhaust fan noise is super intense (and even with it on, the air quality in the kitchen when cooking on the stovetop is not great). I haven't taken off the cover yet to get more info on the existing brand/model.
I've seen suggestions for quiet hood vents, but not a ceiling exhaust. Would love ideas of where to start with this.

boom box effect, the vibration of the ceiling, make sure the fan is firmly mounted on the 2x4

For quieter and more effective, add a hood that drops/hangs down from the 9 foot ceiling to 30-36 inches above the stove/range.

Image Source, no endorsement implied

Image Source, no endorsement implied
Trying to exhaust a stove from 6 feet away is going to be loud and ineffective no matter what fan you put in there.
The other design decision you can make to limit noise in the kitchen is to locate the fan at or near the far end of the exhaust duct, rather than at the intake end. Either all the way outside the house, (has to be a vent fan designed for that placement, of course) or just before the vent exits the house.

The problem is that the range is basically in the center of the kitchen/dining room, which is separated by a counter from the wall that ends with the range. The kitchen has a wraparound U-shaped counter, with one end of the U in the center of the room with the range. (The other side ends in the fridge.) So dropping a hood in the middle of the room would have a big impact on the feel of the room. Are there small/compact hoods that might work for this sort of situation?

There are dropped hoods with a chimney section basically the size of the duct and a flare at the lower end. Fact is, if the range is there, you need a hood there, and if you don't want a hood there, you either move the range or rip out several cabinets and stick in the inferior and also loud downdraft option. https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/129681/34242 Or stop using the range and enjoy the "look" of the kitchen while ordering takeout...

@LizzyH if only you'd provided us with photos or sketches showing the actual location of the range and the existing vent...

If the ceiling exhaust is directly above the range it might be easy to remove it and extend the duct and wiring to a lower location for a standard range hood, adding a cabinet above or a "chimney" style one.
If you want quiet, a good quiet range hood will do the job but also, combined with strategically opened windows and doors will exhaust the entire kitchen better than a poor noisy old ceiling one.

The problem is that the range is basically in the center of the kitchen/dining room, which is separated by a counter from the wall that ends with the range. The kitchen has a wraparound U-shaped counter, with one end of the U in the center of the room with the range. (The other side ends in the fridge.) So dropping a hood in the middle of the room would have a big impact on the feel of the room. Are there small/compact hoods that might work for this sort of situation?

There are solutions but the point of my answer was "cheap and easy" and I think the constraint of not wanting a hulking machine hanging from the ceiling in the middle of the room is reasonable but the solutions are expensive.  A retracting hood or a downdraft one through the floor or a minor renovation moving the range.
